# Let $γ : [0, 1] → C$ be given by $ γ(t) := 2 + e^{2πit}$. Compute the path integral $\int_{\gamma} z^2$dz

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$γ : [0, 1] → C$  be given by $  γ(t) := 2 + e^{2πit}$
Compute the path integral $\int_{\gamma} z^2 dz$

My solution: using the defintion of the path integral $\int_{\gamma} z^2 dz = \int^1_{0} (2+e^{2πit})^2.(2\pi ie^{2\pi i t})dt =  \int^1_{0} 8\pi i e^{2\pi i t} + 8\pi i e^{4\pi i t}+ 2\pi i e^{6\pi i t} dt = [4e^{2\pi i t} + 2e^{4\pi i t} + \frac{1}{3} e^{6\pi i t}]^1_0 $

= $4e^{2\pi i } + 2e^{4\pi i } + \frac{1}{3} e^{6\pi i } - (4+2+\frac{1}{3}) $
= $4e^{2\pi i } + 2e^{4\pi i } + \frac{1}{3} e^{6\pi i }  - \frac{19}{3}$

am i correct or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{2n\pi i}=1\,,\forall n\in\Bbb{Z}$$ . So your answer should be $0$.

More Generally if you integrate an holomorphic function over a closed curve you get $0$ . This is  [Cauchy-Goursat's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) .

Comment: where does it say that $n \in Z$?

Comment: @tp1 . The last line of the op has expressions of the form $e^{2n\pi i} $ .

Comment: $e^{2n\pi i}$ is just the unit circle with the rule: $e^{ix} = \cos{x}+i\sin{x}$.

Comment: You really need to revise your complex numbers. $e^{2n\pi i}$ is just one complex number. Specifically it is the function $e^{ix}$ evaluated at $x=2n\pi$. And it's value equals $1$ as $\cos(2n\pi)=1,\sin(2n\pi)=0$.

Comment: I'm somehow thinking that $n \in [0..1]$ instead of $n \in Z$.

Comment: Alright. I think I understand your confusion.I am specifically refering to the last line of the op. The op has evaluated the integral correctly . But he has not simplified the answer. When he is writing $e^{2\pi i}$ or $e^{6\pi i}$ then they are just $1$ and when added off they cancel the $\frac{19}{6}$ can give $0$ as the answer. The entire curve is parametrized by the equation $z=2+e^{2\pi i t}$ . I am only refering to the last line in the op's question.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer consists of a complex way of writing the number $0$. Since that integral is really equal to $0$; the answer is correct. You can reach the same conclusion observing that the given function ($z\mapsto z^2$) has an antiderivative ($z\mapsto z^3/3$) and that therefore its integral along *any* closed path is equal to $0$.